# Java Multiple Input Dialog

Tags: java, input, dialog

I have a Java application and I want to open a new dialog from the main interface where the user can enter his name, surname and country and then click ok. How can I open a dialog which has a number of different input fields and then save that information in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Extend [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) and add some [JTextFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and maybe some [JComboBoxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). then finish it off with some [JButtons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html).

You could also look into [JGoodies Forms framework](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/index.html); it's nice and free.

**EDIT:** Composition example

Based on Pete's comment I dug up [this example](http://stein.everybody.org/journal/posts/swing-example/) using composition rather than overriding JDialog.

You would want to add getter like

```
public String getFirstName() {
      return field.getTest();
}
```

To gain access to relevant input.

Comment: Only extend JDialog (or any other class) if you need to override one or more of its behaviours.

Comment: I am not really looking to override any features, just have a set of text boxes that are relevant to my application. I am going create a class that extends JDialog. I will save the text in attributes and then access those attributes from the main application to get the text.

not sure how clear my explanation was

Comment: So Pete do you recommend to Wrap the JDialog or how would go about it?

Answer (score 0):

This [forum post](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-gui/4126/custom-JDialog) could be helpful.

> One possibility to make a custom
>   JDialog is to create a custom JPanel
>   with all the bells and whistles that
>   you need and use that as the Component
>   in one of the static JOptionPane
>   functions.

Answer (score 0):

With java and swing you have to write some code. I build a library which creates a dialog with different inputs in a few lines. It's called [UiBooster](https://github.com/Milchreis/UiBooster#form-dialog).

```
FilledForm form = new UiBooster()
        .createForm("Personal informations")
        .addText("Whats your first name?")
        .addTextArea("Tell me something about you")
        .addSelection(
                "Whats your favorite movie?",
                Arrays.asList("Pulp Fiction", "Bambi", "The Godfather", "Hangover"))
        .show();
```

[image]